# Serverless azure offline: value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')

Tags: azure-functions, serverless, serverless-offline

I'm experimenting for the first time with serverless functions.
More specifically am I writing a nodejs12 function that I want to deploy on the azure cloud.

I'm using [serverless](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/azure/guide/quick-start/) for this. When trying to run the default generated functions locally (hello & goodbye) using `sls offline`, I'm always getting following error:

`Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')`

While I'm certain this is not null as you can see in my serverless.yml:

```
service: test

provider:
  name: azure
  region: North Europe
  runtime: nodejs12

plugins:
  - serverless-azure-functions

package:
  exclude:
    - local.settings.json
    - .vscode/**

functions:
  hello:
    handler: src/handlers/hello.sayHello
    events:
      - http: true
        x-azure-settings:
          methods:
            - GET
          authLevel: anonymous

  goodbye:
    handler: src/handlers/goodbye.sayGoodbye
    events:
      - http: true
        x-azure-settings:
          methods:
            - GET
          authLevel: anonymous
```

Not sure what the issue is here? I'm using the latest version of `serverless (1.71.3)` and `serverless-azure-functions (2.0.2)` and `azure-functions-core-tools (2.7.2508)`.

The full output logs can you find [here.](https://pastebin.com/g7BMzx6L)

**EDIT 1:** even with core-tools version 3 it doesn't work. I get the same error.

**EDIT 2:** I found [this issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/1924), but cleaning the cache did not work for me. I'm also on MacOS Catalina.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was a bug in `serverless-azure-functions` which is reported by a dev from `azure-functions-core-tools` as you can see [here.](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/2002)